# Why isn't the Leuckart reaction used to make (meth)amphetamine?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, amines, organic-reduction, drugs, chemistry-in-fiction

For example, in Breaking Bad, they synthesize meth from phenylacetone.

Why not just use methylammonium formate, if they already have methylamine?

Comment: @OscarLanzi There's many methods and both used in the show are fine.

Comment: @OscarLanzi iirc they used aluminum with the methylamine (and presumably HgCl2?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_amination#In_popular_culture